# Getting linker error when trying to import lua headers into C++ project?

Tags: c++, xcode, lua

I'm trying to write some C++ functions that can be run from Lua. However, when I try to import the header files, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_luaL_loadfilex", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_luaL_newstate", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_luaL_openlibs", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_lua_close", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_lua_pcallk", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_lua_pushcclosure", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_lua_setglobal", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've already added the file path to the **Header Search Paths** option in the Build Settings.

Here is the import code:

```
extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like the compiler Lua link flag is not being invoked. Do you have a log with the command prompt compiler commands being invoked ?

Comment: @Niloct You mean all the stuff in the log beforehand? Here it is: https://gist.github.com/charles-l/8854752

Comment: I don't see the lua library path in that link line. Did you ever add to the lib-search path in your project settings. It is likely you did when you added the lua header-path, but you may have missed it (or I did while reviewing the link line).

Comment: @WhozCraig, I added it to the library search path just now, but it's still return the the same errors. Are there any other search paths I have to set other than the library search path and the header search path?

Comment: You probably want to link the libs as well, now that the compiler knows where to find them. Is the dylib added to your project frameworks? or is the appropriate -l flag being passed to the linker? (sry, i never linked with lua before, so no joy on what the name of the lib is).

Comment: `Using gcc on the command line, add the -I./lua.framework/Contents/Headers option (assuming the lua.framework is in the same directory).`

Comment: http://www.idevgames.com/forums/thread-3181.html

Comment: @Niloct should I be using a framework? Right now, I just have the source code in a folder that I'm adding to the search paths. I couldn't find any C++ frameworks for XCode (I could only find objective-c frameworks).

Comment: @CharlesL I only found frameworks for 5.0.2, I updated my answer, please try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a first working version, get the library [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.2.1/Other%20Libraries/lua-5.2.1_MacOS107_lib.tar.gz/download), extract the header files **and** the `.a` file into the same directory as the project file which has the code you posted in your question, then try to compile and link normally.

You may keep the references locally as in your question:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "lua.h"
    #include "lualib.h"
    #include "lauxlib.h"
}
```

Later you refine your environment if that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is a link error not a compile error. The linker (called "ld") is complaining that it can't resolve symbols related to Lua. Make sure you have -llua52 in your link command so your library links to the Lua shared library (might be -llua or -llua5.2 on your system), and tell the linker where to find that lib via -Lpath/to/Lua/lib/folder.

Comment: He needs to use Lua 5.2 because `luaL_loadfilex` does not exist in 5.1.